# How to redirect whole domain with subdomains to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, subdomain

I need to redirect:

`anything.domain.com` and `domain.com/anything`

to

```
domain2.com
```

I've tried this `.htaccess` code with wildcard:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domena2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it still redirects `domain1.com/123` to `domain2.com/123` and not to `domain2.com` and my subdomains are not redirected at all.

Comment: If it's not redirecting the subdomains then it would seem your subdomains are pointing to a different area of the filesystem (or an entirely different filesystem?), or you have other `.htaccess` files on these subdomains? If you only want to redirect to `domain2.com/` (ie. the document root) then why are you using a `$1` backreference and capturing the subpattern in the `RewriteRule`?

Comment: i get this code from someone on another forum , i don't know exactly how it works .My problem is a little more complicated , i've bought an expired domain that have a lot of traffic i know that it have at least one subdomain but maybe more , that's why id like redirect anything to my domain without knowing all subdomains

Answer (score 0):

> i've bought an expired domain that have a lot of traffic i know that it have at least one subdomain but maybe more , that's why id like redirect anything to my domain without knowing all subdomains

If the subdomains are not actually configured then that's your problem.

You would need to configure all the subdomains in DNS (or perhaps create a *wildcard* subdomain), otherwise they won't even resolve (which is presumably the error you are getting in the browser?). If they don't resolve then they don't reach your site and the code in `.htaccess` is not even processed.

Also, if you wish to redirect to the home page then remove the `$1` backreference (as mentioned in my comment). However, redirecting everything to the home page is not necessarily good for SEO. Google is likely to see these links as a soft-404 anyway and will soon be dropped from the SERPs.

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain2\.com
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com/ [R=302,L]
```

This redirects all requests that are not for `domain2.com` to the root of `domain2.com`.

Make sure your browser cache is cleared before testing, as 301s are cached hard by the browser. For this reason, change the above `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK.

> i get this code from someone on another forum

It's important to understand what you are copy/pasting into your `.htaccess` file, as it can very quickly break your site.